# How to read parameters from GET request in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

How to read parameters from GET request in CherryPy ? I generate request from JQuery like

```
$.get(
    "http://localhost:8080/temp",
    "{a:10}",
    function(data) { alert(data); },
    "html"
);
```

and I have class temp with @cherrypy.expose function index(self). How to extract data from GET request ?

Answer (score 13):

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, param)
```

where `param` is your GET param

Answer (score 11):

As virhilo mentioned, you can take named parameters in with your method.

Also, you can read `cherrypy.request.params`.

Answer (score 8):

With both **POST** and **GET** (and **PUT**, **PATCH**, etc...) you can use:

```
cherrypy.request.params.get(key_name)
```

Where `key_name` is the key name you want to get.