# Servlet equivalent in Python?

Tags: java, android, python, servlets

On client side , following android code would make the call to the local server :

```
        String link = "http://localhost:8080/test/cgi-bin/test.py";
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(link);

        HttpURLConnection client =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            jo.put("desc","xyz");

            String data2 =  jo.toString();
            client.setRequestMethod("Post");
        //    client.setRequestProperty("key","value");
            client.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputPost = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            outputPost.write(data2);
            outputPost.flush();
            outputPost.close();
```

Earlier I was using servlets to interact with DB as the code below : 
Using HttpServlet class , i could get the request and its parameters :

```
public class ServletXYZ extends HttpServlet {

 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String method = request.getParameter("method");
```

Is there any way in python which allows me to do the same (getting parameter values from request) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) as a general purpose HTTP server framework.  Ultimately to do the same as the servlet, there are many links - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211381/how-to-read-parameters-from-get-request-in-cherrypy) seems to be pretty much what you want.

Comment: i started with cherrypy , would you know where to put my .py file which contains the processing of request and sending of response . And accordingly what url do i need to pass as link in client side

Comment: by where i mean , certain directory of apache server which i am using locally